# cannot create line on my c# chart

Tags: c#, winforms

I don't have an error, but it doesn't create line on points. I have 4 points on the graph but no line.

```
    private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int x1 = Convert.ToInt16(textBox1.Text);
        int x2 = Convert.ToInt16(textBox2.Text);
        int x3 = Convert.ToInt16(textBox3.Text);
        int x4 = Convert.ToInt16(textBox4.Text);

        int y1 = Convert.ToInt16(textBox1.Text);
        int y2 = Convert.ToInt16(textBox2.Text);
        int y3 = Convert.ToInt16(textBox3.Text);
        int y4 = Convert.ToInt16(textBox4.Text);
        x1 = 15; x2 = 19; x3 = 24; x4 = 29;
        this.chart1.Series["HR"].Points.AddXY(x1, y1);
        this.chart1.Series["HR"].Points.AddXY(x2, y2);
        this.chart1.Series["HR"].Points.AddXY(x3, y3);
        this.chart1.Series["HR"].Points.AddXY(x4, y4);
    }

    public void DrawlinePoint(PaintEventArgs e)
    { 
        //Create pen.
        Pen blackPen = new Pen(Color.Black,3);
        // Create coordinates of points that define line.
        int x1 = 11;
        int y1 = 0;
        int x4 = 37;
        int y4 = 220;
        //DrawLine to screen.
        e.Graphics.DrawLine(blackPen, x1,y1,x4, y4);
    }
```

Comment: please help me to solve the chart

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where do you invoke the `DrawlinePoint` method from? Judging from the `PointEventArgs` parameter you have to do that on `Paint` event of the chart. Do you add an event handler to the chart `Paint` event? If no then you can add it in the constructor of the form:

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.chart1.Paint += (sender, args) => this.DrawlinePoint(args);
}
```

(As a side note, if you don't use .Net 3.5 or higher you will have to change the lambda to a standard event handler.)

Comment: I want to put calculate 80% of that drawn line (x1,y1) & (x4,y4). Is it possible to help me with method for the calculation pLease? @PiotWlkowski

Comment: It's bit different issue, not really related to painting in winforms or to programming in general. Do you want the line to be of 80% of length of the original one? Do you want it to start at the same place but end 80% length earlier? If so just calculate 80% value of x4 and y4. `x4 = x4 * 0.8` and `y4 = y4 * 0.8`. It's naïve solution but anything more elaborate should  be equally easy to achieve. Will leave figuring out the details for you.